# Spring java.util.Date bean

Tags: spring, date

I wanna make java.util.Date bean. Date must be specified in human readable format (for example as string "02/25/1990").
How do it easiest (without using deprecated Date() constructors)?

```
<bean id="date" class="java.util.Date" >
    <!-- Need 02/25/1990 -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found easier solution:

```
<bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="date" factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
    <constructor-arg value="02/25/1990"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the non-deprecated `Date(long)` constructor:

```
<bean id="date" class="java.util.Date">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Long" value="635904000000"/>
</bean>
```

If you want to use a String instead of the milliseconds you could do the following (uses `SimpleDateFormat` to produce a Date, while taking advantage of `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` to invoke it with the specified arguments):

```
<bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
   <constructor-arg value="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</bean>

<bean id="date" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetObject" ref="dateFormat"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="parse"/>
   <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="java.lang.String">02/25/1990</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Of course you need to use the correct pattern for SimpleDateFormat or could end up with unexpected results

Comment: geoand, thanks! What about without milliseconds? It is comfortable to use date in string format.

Comment: What do you mean? Like calling new Date()?

Comment: I'll look into that and get back to you in a little while

Comment: There are many examples with CustomDateEditors. But it works only with date properties.

Comment: Yes I know, I saw them :)

Comment: I made some minor mistakes, please be sure to check the latest update